# Get first N rows of file data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to get the first n rows of data in a python file. To get one row I would do `next(file)` and to get many I would do either `file.read(1024)` or `''.join(file.readlines()[:1000]`.

What would be the best way to do this in a function? Here is a start:

```
def get_first_n_rows(self, file, n=1):
    """
    Will return a string of the first N lines of data from the file.
    """
    s = ''
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            s += line
            if line == n: break
    return s
```

Is there a better way where I could use an interator such as `next` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice


def get_first_n_rows(self, file, n=1):
    """
    Will return a string of the first N lines of data from the file.
    """
    s = ''
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in islice(f, n):
            s += line
    return s
```

From the linked documentation:

> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If
>   start is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until
>   start is reached. Afterward, elements are returned consecutively
>   unless step is set higher than one which results in items being
>   skipped.

Comment: thanks, could you please briefly explain what `islice` does, or link to the docs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_first_n_rows(self, file, n=1):
    with open(file) as fp:
        return "".join(next(fp) for _ in range(0, n))
```

or alternatively if you want a list of the lines:

```
def get_first_n_rows(self, file, n=1):
    with open(file) as fp:
        return list(next(fp) for _ in range(0, n))
```